# How to pass in Kerberos keytab+principal in Spark submit job to authenticate BOTH Spark and Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

My code is at a point where I can successfully authenticate Kerberized Livy to submit a Spark job, and the issue now is that in the Spark submit job parameters, I can only pass in one set of keytab+principal, and so far I am passing in my Spark keytab+principal so that the Spark submit job can even be submitted, but soon after starting the Spark job I get an error - something about the wrong Yarn user, and I don't know how to proceed with that.

Below is the error I get. I have Googled this error and tried all the solutions I found but nothing worked so far.

Things I've tried:

Making sure the `spark` user exists, and that it is able to be authenticated via keytab+principal.

Trying to run the Spark submit with different principals (hadoop, spark, yarn).

Making sure the user/principal is present on all Hadoop nodes.

Making sure my scala jar is valid and correct.

```
main : run as user is spark
main : requested yarn user is spark
User spark not found
```

By the way, why does it say user spark not found? I checked my users list, spark is one of the users.

Comment: Hadoop has to map Kerberos principals (UPNs such as `foo@REA.LM` and SPNs such as `yarn/host1234.doma.in@REA.LM`) to Linux users. These Linux users must be present on all nodes, master and worker. They may be defined as local users or LDAP users (via e.g. SSSD)

Comment: If you are not already familiar with Kerberos, brace yourself, the learning curve is steep. Cf. "Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_.

Comment: thanks I solved it by checking that livy user is correctly configured on my workers. They existed but not in the correct user group. thanks!